# Create a file inside a folder using MimeType inside Google Drive using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type

```
function msWordExt() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
    var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
     var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");
    folder.createFile("MS Word",get,MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD);
}
```

**Goal 1**: When I try to make the same code to create a Google Slides or any other google or Opendocument extension it does not work.

```
function msSlidesExt() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
    var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
     var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");
    folder.createFile("PLAIN TEXT",get,MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES);
}
```

This above code will not create a Google Slides file inside my specified Drive.

**Goal 2** : How do I create a function where instead of hard coding this  `DriveApp.getFolderById("1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc");`
Is it possible to make this dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create the files by selecting from the following 9 mimeTypes by putting a text data.

  - `MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS`
  - `MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES`
  - `MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS`
  - `MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD`
  - `MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT`
  - `MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL`
  - `MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_TEXT`
  - `MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_PRESENTATION`
  - `MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_SPREADSHEET`
- You want to create the file in the specific folder.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, above files cannot be directly created by `DriveApp.createFile()`. Although the mimeType can be given to the file, the file content is not the same with the mimeType. So in this case, it is required to use a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose the following workaround. The flow of workaround is as follows.

1. Create a file as Google Docs (Document, Slides and Spreadsheet).
2. Download the file with the expected mimeType by exporting the Google Docs with the export method in Drive API.
3. Create the exported file to the specific folder as the file.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And please set the variables of `filename, folderId, mimeType, get` in the function of `main`. Then, please run the function of `main`.

```
const createFile = (filename, folderId, mimeType, content) => {
  const docs = () => {
    const d = DocumentApp.create(filename);
    d.getBody().editAsText().setText(content);
    d.saveAndClose();
    return d.getId();
  }
  const slides = () => {
    const s = SlidesApp.create(filename);
    s.getSlides()[0].insertTextBox(content);
    s.saveAndClose();
    return s.getId();
  }
  const sheets = () => {
    const s = SpreadsheetApp.create(filename);
    s.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue(content);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    return s.getId();
  }
  const convert = {
    [MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS]: docs,
    [MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES]: slides,
    [MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS]: sheets,
    [MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD]: docs,
    [MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT]: slides,
    [MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL]: sheets,
    [MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_TEXT]: docs,
    [MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_PRESENTATION]: slides,
    [MimeType.OPENDOCUMENT_SPREADSHEET]: sheets,
  };
  const fileId = convert[mimeType]();
  if (mimeType.includes("google")) {
    Drive.Files.patch({parents: [{id: folderId}]}, fileId);
    return fileId;
  }
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${fileId}/export?mimeType=${mimeType}`;
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`}}).getBlob();
  const id = Drive.Files.insert({title: filename, parents: [{id: folderId}]}, blob);
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
  return id;
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1MUwH0Cm1cwHcTWSCGPp2SePbzs_4QQmtjwOEWOrOkMw');
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var get = sheetName.getRange(2,3).getValue();

  const filename = "sample";
  const folderId = "1rsicZccurujGp5Ye5HUecBIAPf3_h5Pc";
  const mimeType = MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES;
  const fileId = createFile(filename, folderId, mimeType, get);
  console.log(fileId);
}
```

- Function of `main` returns the file ID of the created file.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, as the sample case, the text data is simply put to the Google Docs. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is way too complicated for me... I am doing a different way.